# Redis how to use incr value in mset using multi

Tags: node.js, redis

Is it possible to use `multi.incr(key)` outcome in `multi.hmset`?

```
var multi = client.multi();
multi.incr('seq:thread');//say incr => 1
multi.hmset('user:001', {name: 'name', threadid: <need incr value here>});
multi.exec(function(err,data)){ .. });
```

My objective is to increment the counter (thread-id) and set it into desired user in a **transaction**. If its not possible is there an alternate to achieve such atomicity?

Comment: You can use `WATCH`. See the Redis topic on [transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions). Another way would be to do it in a script.

Comment: @LinusGThiel Thanks for the pointer, WATCH worked..